# How can I get CentOS kernel source code

Tags: linux, centos, kernel

I'm build a 3rd tool and it dependents on `Linux kernel` source code.

The tool specifies the release version of `Linux kernel` by `uname -r`, the result is:

`3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64`

However, I didn't find this source code under `/usr/src/`, I think I should install the source code myself.

I use command below to install it:
`yum install kernel-source kernel-devel`

The good news is that I got the source code under `/usr/src/kernels`, the bad news is that the version is `3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64`, it's not consistent with the output of `uname -r`.

How can I get exactly the source code which is consistent with the version specified by `uname -r`?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Building a kernel module : `# yum install kernel kernel-devel` ... I.e. kernel / kernel-devel must be an exact match. ... "kernel-devel" provides `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have luck by specifying the kernel version via `yum`, if that's available via the repos that you have access to.

```
sudo yum install -y kernel-devel-3.10.0
```

If you have the source RPM, you can use rpm2cpio and cpio.

```
rpm2cpio kernel-3.10.0-862.el7.src.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

Here's a [mirror to kernel-3.10.0-862.el7.src.rpm](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/26/dist/93/size/98216668/name/kernel-3.10.0-862.el7.src.rpm) that I found via a quick search on google. So the full set of commands would be:

```
wget ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/7Server/en/RHEV/SRPMS/kernel-3.10.0-862.el7.src.rpm

rpm2cpio kernel-3.10.0-862.el7.src.rpm | cpio -idmv
```